# Looking to Better Understand Conversions to Unit Vectors via dividing by magnitude

Tags: vectors

I understand that in order to scale a vector to its unit vector, we divide the vector by its magnitude (which is performing scalar multiplication to rescale the vector to having a magnitude of 1). I get that the algebra will work out, but it still feels non-obvious to me why this operation results in a unit vector each time.
Can someone provide me an intuitive explanation that will help make things 'click' for why dividing by the magnitude results in a unit vector?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Maybe first consider the case when the magnitude of the vector is an integer? E.g. if we have a vector of length 5, we can chop it up into five equal parts each of length 1, i.e. unit vectors. Dividing by the magnitude is just chopping up the vector into a suitable number of equal parts.

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, the reason the conversion

$$\vec v \longrightarrow \frac{1}{\|\vec v\|} \vec v$$

gives a unit vector is because you're shrinking it down by a factor precisely equal to that vector's norm. (You may be taking a vector of length $2$, for instance, and shrink it down by a factor of $1/2$; a vector of length $1/3$ and triple its length; and so on.)

Algebraically, then, for a (nonzero) vector $\vec v$ with norm $\|\vec v\|$, we have

$$\left\| \frac{1}{\|\vec v\|} \|\vec v\| \right\|= \frac{1}{\|\vec v\|} \|\vec v\|=1$$

i.e. the magnitude of the new vector is $1$.

(This uses the property that $\|\alpha \vec v\| = |\alpha| \cdot \|\vec v\|$ for any scalar $\alpha$; note that norms are always nonnegative scalars, so we can drop the absolute values on that scalar.)